# ipython cluster and multiprocessing pool parallelizing python code

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, jupyter-notebook

I have some computationally intensive and repetitive task (`sklearn BallTree` to be specific) running on a very large database (multi million lines of data).

I  heard ipython notebooks (jupyter) runs a parallel cluster. I kept the # of engines as 8 (I have i7 second-gen quad core mac). Not knowing if it does anything, I ran the code on 100,000 database and it took about 12 hours in a jupyter notebook (CPU usage very less<10% used by python).

I was further looking to parallelize the code and found `multiprocessing.Pool()` and `pool.map`. I ran the code pooling with `pool(8)` in the very same notebook. The total number of processes in the activity monitor seemed to increase but the code is still running slow (around 12 hours+) and CPU usage still very less<10%. I don't think it optimized or improved anything.

I am a total noob to parallel computing and just want my code to run as fast as it can on my machine. What am I doing wrong?

How do I utilize the cores to the maximum and run the code as quickly and efficiently as possible with min. time? Any help in this regard will be great.

Comment: This purely depends on the code you wish to run - you can dedicate a CPU core to each of your processes but that won't mean anything if those processes are sleeping or waiting for I/O most of the time.

Comment: I am running `sklearn.neighbors.BallTree` with a custom metric. How do I optimize reducing the sleeping/waiting time? any way to find out how it is distributing the work across processors and which ones are waiting... any example code?